# How to find out standard deviation of estimated positions against real world position

Tags: python, standard-deviation

I hope the title isn't too confusing but it's the best I could think of (feel free to suggest better titles!)

I have a physical sensor placed at a fixed location in a room, say (1, 1, 1) in a coordinate system. This sensor is able to estimate its position within the coordinate system. I let the sensor estimate the position 10 times a second for a time period of 30 seconds, so in total I have 300 position estimations which are saved to a file.

Now, in order to evaluate the position estimations, I calculated the distance from every estimation to the reference point (1, 1, 1) and saved all distances to a list. I'd like to find out the standard deviation of the distances to the reference point (1, 1, 1).

I am not that familiar with calculating standard deviations but as multiple explanations and tutorials suggested, I should
1) calculate the mean of all distances
2) substract the mean from every single distance and square it
3) add all values from step 2) to a list and calculate their mean
4) take the square root of the mean

But, I think I shouldn't use the mean of the calculated distances in step 2) but instead use the value of 0 because I don't want to calculate the standard deviation of the calculated distances to their mean but to my reference point (1, 1, 1). Since my reference point obviously has a distance of 0 to itself, I thought that this might be the right approach.

Here's my python script:

```
import sys
from math import sqrt, pow

# Returns the amount of samples collected - necessary for mean and standard deviation calculations
def get_sample_count(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

def distanceBetweenTwoPoints2D(sample_point, reference_point):
    return sqrt(pow(sample_point[0] - reference_point[0], 2) + pow(sample_point[1] - reference_point[1], 2))

def distanceBetweenTwoPoints3D(sample_point, reference_point):
    return sqrt(pow(sample_point[0] - reference_point[0], 2) + pow(sample_point[1] - reference_point[1], 2) + pow(sample_point[2] - reference_point[2], 2))

def standard_deviation(distances_2D, sample_distance_mean_2D, distances_3D, sample_distance_mean_3D, sample_count):
    squared_distances_2D = []
    squared_distances_3D = []
    for distance in distances_2D:
        squared = pow(distance - 0, 2)
        squared_distances_2D.append(squared)
    for distance in distances_3D:
        squared = pow(distance - 0, 2)
        squared_distances_3D.append(squared)

    std2D = sqrt(sum(squared_distances_2D) / sample_count)
    std3D = sqrt(sum(squared_distances_3D) / sample_count)

    return std2D, std3D

def evaluateData(filename, reference_point):
    sample_x_mean = 0.0
    sample_y_mean = 0.0
    sample_z_mean = 0.0
    distances_2D = []
    distances_3D = []

    sample_count = get_sample_count(filename)

    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            x = float(line.split(',')[0])
            y = float(line.split(',')[1])
            z = float(line.split(',')[2])

            # Add individual coordinates to means
            sample_x_mean += x
            sample_y_mean += y
            sample_z_mean += z

            # Calculate distance in 2D and 3D and add to distances lists
            sample_point = [x, y, z]
            sample_distance_2D = distanceBetweenTwoPoints2D(sample_point, reference_point)
            sample_distance_3D = distanceBetweenTwoPoints3D(sample_point, reference_point)
            distances_2D.append(sample_distance_2D)
            distances_3D.append(sample_distance_3D)

    sample_x_mean /= sample_count
    sample_y_mean /= sample_count
    sample_z_mean /= sample_count
    sample_distance_mean_2D = sum(distances_2D) / sample_count
    sample_distance_mean_3D = sum(distances_3D) / sample_count
    std2D, std3D = standard_deviation(distances_2D, sample_distance_mean_2D, distances_3D, sample_distance_mean_3D, sample_count)

    return sample_count, sample_x_mean, sample_y_mean, sample_z_mean, sample_distance_mean_2D, sample_distance_mean_3D, std2D, std3D

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    direction = filename.split('(')[0]
    x_reference = float((filename.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split('_')[0]).replace(',', '.'))
    y_reference = float((filename.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split('_')[1]).replace(',', '.'))
    z_reference = float((filename.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split('_')[2]).replace(',', '.'))
    reference_point = [x_reference, y_reference, z_reference]

    print("\n")
    sample_count, x_mean, y_mean, z_mean, distance_mean_2D, distance_mean_3D, std2D, std3D = evaluateData(filename, reference_point)
    print("DIRECTION: {}, SAMPLE COUNT: {}".format(direction, sample_count))
    print("X REFERENCE: {}, Y REFERENCE: {}, Z REFERENCE: {}".format(x_reference, y_reference, z_reference))
    print("X MEAN: {}, Y MEAN: {}, Z MEAN: {}".format(x_mean, y_mean, z_mean))
    print("DISTANCE MEAN 2D: {}, DISTANCE MEAN 3D: {}".format(distance_mean_2D, distance_mean_3D))
    print("STD2D: {}, STD3D: {}".format(std2D, std3D))
    print("\n")
```

Can anybody prove me right or wrong please?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1) If you're already calculating the distance between the reference point and your observation point in distanceBetweenTwoPoints[23]D(), you wouldn't want to use the reference point as the mean. That's already sort of baked into the calculation.

2) math.stdev() will calculate standard deviation for you.

Comment: 1) I don't understand what you mean. Where do I meake use of a mean in distanceBetweenTwoPoints()? And also, what should I use instead?
2) I know about math.stdev() but math.stdev() doesn't solve my problem because I explicitly don't want to calculate the usual standard deviation of the calculated distances but I want to find out how they vary from my reference point.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to correctly calculate the distances to the reference point, and then calculate the root mean square of these distances.

(There is a minor efficiency issue with evaluating the square root when applying Pythagoras' theorem only to square the distances again during the RMS calculation, but for 300 points it is not worth worrying about.)

If the stated aim is to calculate the standard deviation of the distances, then you do need -- as you have indicated -- to subtract off the mean of the distances before you evaluate the root mean square, because the standard deviation is not the root mean square of the distances themselves, but instead the root mean square of the deviation from the mean.  This is not what you have calculated.

Which of these is more appropriate will depend on what you are trying to measure.  Suppose for example that all of your estimates are at the same (non-zero) distance from the reference point.  The *root mean square* of those distances will be equal to that value.  But the *standard deviation* of the distances will be equal to zero because it is a measure of spread in the variable concerned, and all the values (distance from the reference point) are equal.

If you are trying to evaluate the accuracy of the the measurements, then the root mean square distance (rather than the standard deviation) is probably of greater relevance.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'd like to evaluate the accuracy. I was thinking about the standard deviation because I have multiple fixed points in my room where I want to collect data, too. So after all, I wanted to see where the estimated positions vary the most and where the least from the reference point (and _not_ where they vary compared to their own mean because that information seems pretty useless for me, doesn't it?) But as it seems, my assumption is wrong and calculating the standard deviation as I did is not the right way to go, right?

Comment: Or in other words, it does not make sense to calculate the standard deviation against a fixed point _which_  _is_  _not_  _the_ _mean_ of the samples as it was my initial question. Could you tell me what other methods can I use to evaluate the accuracy of my system then?  Thanks